# Android ImageView cordinates

Tags: android, position, imageview

I am new to android and I am searching for solution to get x and y cordinates of ImageView. I tried with LocationOnScreen, but it is not working. I have to note that I am using android animations to move ImageView before getting it's postion. It is important to me that it works on lower APIs - 2.2, 2,3, and up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getLeft()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29) and [`getTop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29):

```
x = imageView.getLeft();
y = imageView.getTop();
```

More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Position

Comment: That is working, but I have to get the position while animation of moving is still in proccess. Thank you